# jQuery - When appending a variable, it only adds to 1 select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Link to my fiddle here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0u8Lhbm/)

I am trying to build up options for a select with jQuery and add them to 2 different selects, here is my mark up and code:

```js
var selectValues = [{ "ownerid": " ", "name": " "}, {  "ownerid": 123,  "name":"Tom"}, {  "ownerid": 345,  "name": "Dick"}, {  "ownerid": 888,  "name": "Harry"}];

$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
  var myoption = $("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", value.ownerid)
    .text(value.name);

  $('#select1').append(myoption);
  $('#select2').append(myoption);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select 1</label>
<select id="select1"></select>
<label>Select 2</label>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

However 'myoption' is only append to 1 select and not the other.

**Question**: how do i append it to both without declaring an identical variable?

cheers!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z0u8Lhbm/2/ try this

Comment: the HTML element `myoption` can't be at two places at the same time. Consider using `clone()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior, You need to create [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) object and `append()` it to second element.

```
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
    var myoption = $("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", value.ownerid)
        .text(value.name);

    $('#select1').append(myoption);

    //Append cloned object      
    $('#select2').append(myoption.clone());
});
```

```js
var selectValues = [{ "ownerid": " ", "name": " "}, {  "ownerid": 123,  "name":"Tom"}, {  "ownerid": 345,  "name": "Dick"}, {  "ownerid": 888,  "name": "Harry"}];

$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
  var myoption = $("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", value.ownerid)
    .text(value.name);

  $('#select1').append(myoption);
  $('#select2').append(myoption.clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select 1</label>
<select id="select1"></select>
<label>Select 2</label>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

Another approach it to use single selector.

```
$.each(selectValues, function (key, value) {
    var myoption = $("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", value.ownerid)
        .text(value.name);

    $('#select1, #select2').append(myoption);
});
```

```js
var selectValues = [{ "ownerid": " ", "name": " "}, {  "ownerid": 123,  "name":"Tom"}, {  "ownerid": 345,  "name": "Dick"}, {  "ownerid": 888,  "name": "Harry"}];

$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
  var myoption = $("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", value.ownerid)
    .text(value.name);

  $('#select1, #select2').append(myoption);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select 1</label>
<select id="select1"></select>
<label>Select 2</label>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

Comment: @Mr Giggles - just be careful with clone() - for example - if you happened to have an id associated with the element that you are cloning, then the id would also be cloned and would not be unique. Not an issue in this case - but if perhaps the OP wanted to apply an id to each select option then it could get to be an issue.

Comment: +1 for using multiple selectors, nice approach. I prefer this to `.clone()`, and prefer it to my solution :)

Comment: Would agree that multiple selectors is prefereable to clone(), but would also suggest that it equates to my version of using a common class for each of the selectors involved so that it appends the myoption to each in sequence. So its the same solution. Thanks for the upvote :).

Answer (score 0):

Use a class on each select list and append to the classes not the id's. I threw in a console log on the select change to demonstrate that each select list is functional and separate from the other in making the selections.

```js
var selectValues = [{"ownerid":" ","name":" "},
                    {"ownerid":123,"name":"Tom"},
                    {"ownerid":345,"name":"Dick"},
                    {"ownerid":888,"name":"Harry"}]

$.each(selectValues, function (key, value) {
   var myoption = $("<option></option>")
      .attr("value", value.ownerid)
      .text(value.name);
    $('.selectList').append(myoption);
 });

$('.selectList').on('change',function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id') + ": " + $(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select 1</label>
<select id="select1" class="selectList"></select>
<label>Select 2</label>
<select id="select2"  class="selectList"></select>
```

Comment: _for the downvoter:...._  should be comment. I agree with your sentiments. Downvote's without comments are counter productive.

Comment: as directed @Satpal - 
 

Use a class on each select list and append to the classes not the id's. I threw in a console log on the select change to demonstrate that each select list is functional and separate from the other in making the selections.

for the downvoter - why so - it works and appends the option to each select list as required - if you have the guts to downvote - have the balls to own it and say why you don't like this solution. I have no problem being wrong - but I do have a problem with a nameless and reasonless downvote.

Comment: dam - you edited the post before I could do it :) - thanks @Satpal

Answer (score 0):

Here i Made a code for you full working live demo :- https://jsfiddle.net/Arsh_kalsi01/z0u8Lhbm/9/ . Hope it will help You :)

```js
    var selectValues = [{"ownerid":" ","name":" "},{"ownerid":123,"name":"Tom"},{"ownerid":345,"name":"Dick"},{"ownerid":888,"name":"Harry"}];
$.each(selectValues, function (key, value) {           
  $('#select1').append($("<option value='"+value.ownerid+"'>"+value.name+"</option>"));
  $('#select2').append($("<option value='"+value.ownerid+"'>"+value.name+"</option>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label for="select1">Select 1</label>
<select id="select1"></select>
<label for="select1">Select 2</label>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, you can use `.clone()`. You're creating a jQuery object (which is basically a wrapped HTML element), so this object can only be in one place at a time.

An alternative is to fall back to using standard strings, which would then be treated (by the browser) as play HTML elements.

```
var myoption = "<option value='" + value.ownerid + "'>" + value.name + "</option>";

$('#select1').append(myoption);
$('#select2').append(myoption);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/z0u8Lhbm/10/